# Type of an object changing during construction

Tags: c++, inheritance, typeid

I just discoverd the following behaviour : having an object of type `B` derived from type `A`, the final type during the construction of `A` is `A` and not `B`. This can be observed with the following example :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

class A
{
    public:
        A() { std::cout << &typeid(*this) << std::endl; }
};

class B : public A
{
    public:
        B() : A() { std::cout << &typeid(*this) << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;
    return 0;
}
```

A run of this code (compiled with gcc 4.8.5) is the following :

```
0x400ae0
0x400ae0
0x400ac0
```

We can see that the type returned by typeid in `A::A()` is `A` and not `B`, and then the final type changes to become `B`.

**Why ?**

**Is it possible to know the "real" final type during the construction of the parent class ?**

My context is the following :

I have a parent class `Resource` and several classes inheriting from it. I also have a `ResourceManager` notified by each creation of a resource, and having to know the final type of the created resource. What I'm doing to avoid duplicated code is the following, but it doesn't work :

```
class Resource
{
  public:
    Resource() { ResourceManager::notifyCreation(*this); }
    ~Resource() { ResourceManager::notifyDestruction(*this); }
};
class MyResource : public Resource
{
  // I don't have to care to the manager here
};
```

I know I can do the notification in each constructor/destructor of the children, but it's less robust (possible bug if a resource is instanciated without notification to the manager).
**Have you any idea for a workaround ?**

Comment: Umm... `&typeid(....)` ??

Comment: `*this` in `A` is always `A`, why'd you expect the `typeid` to be different?

Comment: @WhiZTiM why ? The return value of typeid is unique in memory for each type.

Comment: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/strange-inheritance#calling-virtuals-from-ctors

Comment: Consider using a factory, possibly the resource manager itself, to construct your resources, then you'll know the final type after the loading is finished.

Comment: You must not compare std::type_info by their memory locations. At least use their [hashes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/hash_code) or better yet use [operator ==()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/operator_cmp) as you are supposed to.

Comment: Unfortunately, hashes is C++11. I don't use it for compatibility reasons.

Comment: uh, because `A()` is the constructor of `A`, so it constructs an `A` and not something else? At that point, the object **is** still an `A`; it has not begun construction of any more derived type, so it is not an instance of any such type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like what you're looking for is [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)

```
template<typename Concrete>
struct Resource
{
    Resource() { ResourceManager::notifyCreation(*static_cast<Concrete*>(this)); }
    ~Resource() { ResourceManager::notifyDestruction(*static_cast<Concrete*>(this)); }
};

struct MyResource : Resource<MyResource>
{

};
```

Note that `MyResource` is not yet finished constructed when the call to `notifyCreation` is made. The address of the `MyResource` instance can be taken, but that's about all that can be done to the instance. (Thanks to Caleth for pointing this out)

In particular from [[class.cdtor]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.cdtor#4)

> If the operand of `typeid` refers to the object under construction or destruction and the static type of the operand is neither the constructor or destructor's class nor one of its bases, the behavior is undefined.

Therefore `ResourceManager` would have to be implemented somewhat like this to enable using `typeid`

```
struct ResourceManager
{
    template<typename T>
    void notifyCreation(T&&)
    {
        add(typeid(T));  // can't apply to an expression
    }
    template<typename T>
    void notifyDestruction(T&&)
    {
        remove(typeid(T));  // can't apply to an expression
    }
};
```

Comment: This is only safe if `MyResource` has no members beyond those of `Resource`

Comment: @Caleth You mean no more base classes? Yes, but the code OP has shown looks like this and I didn't go on to speculate what else OP wants

Comment: No I mean no more data members. They haven't been initialised at the point  where `ResourceManager::notifyCreation` is called, and have be destroyed when `ResourceManager::notifyDestruction` is called

Comment: @Caleth That's a really good point. But it looks like this is intended as the original code attempts to do stuff in the super class.

Comment: Acutally, in my example, the notification passes the element only to apply a typeid on it in the manager. So this is clearly a solution for me.

Comment: @Caduchon If that's what you're doing, I believe this is undefined behaviour: *If the operand of typeid refers to the object under construction or destruction and the static type of the operand is neither the constructor or destructor's class nor one of its bases, the behavior is undefined.*

Answer (score 1):

There is no good way to do it in a constructor as in your example, but you can provide a special constructor for `A`, i.e.

```
 A(const std::type_info &info) {
    std::cout << info.name() << std::endl;
 }
```

and in `B`

```
B() : A(typeid(*this)) {
    std::cout << typeid(*this).name() std::endl;
}
```

if you do it outside the constructor, you can also provide a virtual function in 'A' and overwrite it in 'B'.